# Appscript : Moving many files quickly on google drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I want to move a few hundreds of pdf files stored in Google Drive folder to another folder on the same drive. At the moment, I am using `moveTo` from `DriveApp` as below

```
for (var i=0; i<idList.length; i++){
DriveApp.getFileById(idList[i]).moveTo(destinationFolder);}
```

While this work, it is painfully slow when moving hundreds of files.

Is it possible to significantly improve the moving time?

**EDIT (1)**

In response to @Tanaike comment:

`fileList` is changed to `idList` for clarity reason. The `idList` stores the id values of all the files to be moved.

**EDIT (2)**

Following is the full code sample used based on Tanaike's answer:

```
function main(){

const sourceFolderId = "1G7QNWc1vFTLAbOKdxN_3TiSVCU6962bh";
const destinationFolderId = "1hx7jtdlLQAhOWKgo4MUHgw8QuDWAdMyR";

var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId).getFiles();
var idList = [];

while (files.hasNext()){
  file = files.next();
  idList.push(file.getId())
}

  const size = 100;
  const ar = [...Array(Math.ceil(idList.length / size))].map((_) => idList.splice(0, size));

  ar.forEach(ids => {
    const requests = ids.map(fileId => ({
      method: "PATCH",
      endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?supportsAllDrives=true&enforceSingleParent=true&addParents=${destinationFolderId}`,
      requestBody: {}
    }));
    const res = batchRequests_({ batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests });
    console.log(res.getContentText());
  });

  // DriveApp.createFile(); // This comment line is used for automatically detected a scope of Drive APi by the script editor. So, please don't remove this line
}

function batchRequests_(object) {
  const { batchPath, requests } = object;
  const boundary = "sampleBoundary12345";
  const lb = "\r\n";
  const payload = requests.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    r += `Content-Type: application/http${lb}`;
    r += `Content-ID: ${i + 1}${lb}${lb}`;
    r += `${e.method} ${e.endpoint}${lb}`;
    r += e.requestBody ? `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" ${lb}${lb}` : lb;
    r += e.requestBody ? `${JSON.stringify(e.requestBody)}${lb}` : "";
    r += `--${boundary}${i == a.length - 1 ? "--" : ""}${lb}`;
    return r;
  }, `--${boundary}${lb}`);
  const params = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "post",
    contentType: `multipart/mixed; boundary=${boundary}`,
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    payload,
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/${batchPath}`, params);
}
```

I run into this error:

```
Exception: UrlFetch calls to https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3 are not permitted by your admin
```

I could not verify whether the script works as UrlFetch calls are not allowed in my working environment.

Comment: I think that in your situation, the batch requests with Drive API might be useful. [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/batch) and [Ref2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#batch-requests) But, before I think of a sample script, I have 2 questions. 1. Can I ask you about the detail of the relationship between `fileList` and `id` in your showing script? 2. If `id[i]` is each file ID, can I think that you have already obtained a list including file IDs you want to move?

Comment: @Tanaike `fileList` store the id values of all the files that need to be moved. I have changed the name to `idList` for clarity reason. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize. **This script moves the files from the current folder to the destination folder. So, first, I would like to recommend testing this script using the sample files. Because when you run this script, when the result you don't want occurs, it might be an important problem. Please be careful about this.**

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, how about using the batch requests with Drive API? The batch requests are processed with the asynchronous process. I guessed that this approach might be close to your expected result.

When the batch requests are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### IMPORTANT:

- **This script moves the files from the current folder to the destination folder. So, first, I would like to recommend testing this script using the sample files. Because when you run this script, when the result you don't want occurs, it might be an important problem. Please be careful about this.**

#### Sample script:

In this script, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set your destination folder ID and `idList` including the file IDs.

```js
/**
 * Ref: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script
 * Create a request body of batch requests and request it.
 * 
 * @param {Object} object Object for creating request body of batch requests.
 * @returns {Object} UrlFetchApp.HTTPResponse
 */
function batchRequests_(object) {
  const { batchPath, requests } = object;
  const boundary = "sampleBoundary12345";
  const lb = "\r\n";
  const payload = requests.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    r += `Content-Type: application/http${lb}`;
    r += `Content-ID: ${i + 1}${lb}${lb}`;
    r += `${e.method} ${e.endpoint}${lb}`;
    r += e.requestBody ? `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" ${lb}${lb}` : lb;
    r += e.requestBody ? `${JSON.stringify(e.requestBody)}${lb}` : "";
    r += `--${boundary}${i == a.length - 1 ? "--" : ""}${lb}`;
    return r;
  }, `--${boundary}${lb}`);
  const params = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "post",
    contentType: `multipart/mixed; boundary=${boundary}`,
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    payload,
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/${batchPath}`, params);
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const destinationFolderId = "###"; // Please set your destination folder ID.
  const idList = ["fileId1", "fileId2", "fileId3",,,]; // This is your file list including the file IDs.

  // Ref: https://github.com/tanaikech/UtlApp#splitarray
  const size = 100;
  const ar = [...Array(Math.ceil(idList.length / size))].map((_) => idList.splice(0, size));

  // Use batch requests. In this case, it is run every 100 files. This is a limitation.
  ar.forEach(ids => {
    const requests = ids.map(fileId => ({
      method: "PATCH",
      endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?supportsAllDrives=true&enforceSingleParent=true&addParents=${destinationFolderId}`,
      requestBody: {}
    }));
    const res = batchRequests_({ batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests });
    console.log(res.getContentText());
  });

  // DriveApp.createFile(); // This comment line is used for automatically detected a scope of Drive APi by the script editor. So, please don't remove this line.
}
```

- When this script is run, the files of `idList` are moved to the destination folder of `destinationFolderId`.
- When the number of files is large, after the script was finished, it is required to wait for the processing to move all files.

#### Note:

- In this script, it supposes that you have permission for moving the files. Please be careful about this.
- From `I want to move a few hundreds of pdf files stored in Google Drive folder to another folder on the same drive.`, it supposes that you want to move the files in the same Drive. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Batch requests](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/batch)
- [Batch requests for Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#batch-requests)
- [Efficient File Management using Batch Requests with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script) (Author: me)
- [Method: files.update of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/update)

Comment: Thank a lot for the explanation. One issue is that the original `moveTo` was called as part of the server side code `.gs` file. However, in this case, to use batch requests via Drive API, the processing need to come from client side. So I may need to rethink the way I process the data as a whole.

Comment: @Chris Aung Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `One issue is that the original moveTo was called as part of the server side code .gs file. However, in this case, to use batch requests via Drive API, the processing need to come from client side.` and my proposed script. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: My apologies. I did not read your answer correctly. I will test it out again and accept the answer if it is working. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Chris Aung Thank you for replying and testing it. When my proposed script was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Cooper About `Please explain what you mean by However, in this case, to use batch requests via Drive API, the processing need to come from client side. So I may need to rethink the way I process the data as a whole.`, who do you ask me for an explanation of this?